# Moodle: Access global variables on theme settings pages

Tags: moodle

Is it possible to access a global variable from either $OUTPUT or $PAGE in /admin/settings.php?

I've tried var_dump on them but I get something along the lines of:

object(bootstrap_renderer)#3 (5) { ["initialising":protected]=> bool(false) ["opencontainers":protected]=>

Answer (score 0):

The variables you want to access, if I understand, are fields of the `$PAGE` object. You cannot access directly these fields, because they are protected (you can see it in the class defining the `$PAGE` in */lib/pagelib.php*). However, you can access their value by using a slightly different syntax: if the variable is named `$_myvariable`, you can access it with `$PAGE->myvariable`, (leaving out the underscore).

Example: you want to access `$_pagetype`, `$_url`, and `$_navigation`, use:

```
$test = $PAGE->pagetype;
$test1 = $PAGE->url;
$test2 = $PAGE->navigation;
```

Variables (fields) of the `$OUTPUT` object are also protected, and I did not find a way to access them, though. Here you can probably change the renderer bound to your $OUTPUT variable, and implement public functions returning your fields.